# Is it safe to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 with ROOT partition installed on ZFS to 20.04?

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, compatibility, zfs, 20.04

When installing my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I followed this OpenZFS guide https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-18.04-Root-on-ZFS to install root on ZFS. All went well and my server has been running this setup for over a year (or maybe two :) ). During this time Ubuntu managed to add their support for root on ZFS. Now, when 20.04 LTS is out, I'm wondering is it safe for me to the upgrade? Is my ZFS root compatible with the one that new Ubuntu supports?

Comment: It is not "safe" to upgrade 18.04 to 20.04 yet no matter how it is installed. The upgrade is not recommended yet.

Comment: I agree it is recommended and way safer to wait for the first point release (i.e., 20.04.1). Still I got tempted by all of the new version of packages that comes officially supported with this release including MariaDB 10.3, php-fpm 7.4 and *ZFS 0.8.3* with trim support! I guess everyone need to calculate if the risk is worth it on his own and my question was only about ZFS rpool compatibility between the one from the article and the one in the new Ubuntu. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ran `do-release-upgrade -d` and everything went fine. Then `zpool upgrade -a` and `zpool set autotrim=on rpool` and I'm happy 20.04 user :)

Comment: Do you have any problems with the boot pool? Not all of the ZFS features are supported by GRUB and you executed `zpool upgrade -a`, which upgraded _all_ pools with _all_ features.

Comment: No problems at all with boot pool. I'm only having problems with my incremental backups that, after upgrade, always are full backups... haven't figured out that one yet.